# Merge lists while showing zeros in python

Tags: python, list, count, left-join, django-queryset

I created a Django QuerySet which count values but unfortunately it do not show 0 values. Therefore I want to merge my two list like left join in SQL. I show my  inputs and desired outputs .

**INPUT 1 (Django Query 1):**

I print it out like this:

```
for i in query_1:
     print (i['day'], i['count_1'])  

2018-01-17 00:00:00+01:00 49
2018-01-16 00:00:00+01:00 139
2018-01-15 00:00:00+01:00 144
2018-01-14 00:00:00+01:00 142
2018-01-13 00:00:00+01:00 141
2018-01-12 00:00:00+01:00 144
2018-01-11 00:00:00+01:00 145
2018-01-10 00:00:00+01:00 95
```

**INPUT 2 (Django Query 2):**

I print it out like this:

```
    for i in query_2:
         print (i['day'], i['count_2'])  

   2018-01-17 00:00:00+01:00 2
   2018-01-16 00:00:00+01:00 6
   2018-01-14 00:00:00+01:00 2
   2018-01-13 00:00:00+01:00 4
```

**My desired output would be:**

```
2018-01-17 00:00:00+01:00 49  2
2018-01-16 00:00:00+01:00 139 6
2018-01-15 00:00:00+01:00 144 0
2018-01-14 00:00:00+01:00 142 2
2018-01-13 00:00:00+01:00 141 4
2018-01-12 00:00:00+01:00 144 0
2018-01-11 00:00:00+01:00 145 0
2018-01-10 00:00:00+01:00 95  0
```

I tried this but I failed:

```
for a, b in zip (query_1, query_2)
    if a['day'] == b['day']:
       print (a['count_2']) #It prints only the result of query_2 not both :(
    else:
       print ('0')
```

Comment: *failed* in which way? what happened?

Comment: Sorry I edited my typo. It prints only the 4 value (2,6,2,4) and not print zeros.

Comment: "I created a Django QuerySet which count values but unfortunately it do not show 0 values. Therefore I want to merge my two list like left join in SQL" => perhaps you should fix the problem at the source instead by issuing the exact query you want ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/

Comment: Zipping two lists iterates until the shorter list is exhausted.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I know raw sql method but I want to use only built in possibilities.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Could you give me an example? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Manager.raw()` IS "built in".

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  Sorry I meant in built in that  do not use raw SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_data = [ i['day'] + ' ' + str(i['count_1']) for i in query_1]  
new_data.extend([ i['day'] + ' ' + str(i['count_1']) for i in query_2])
local_dict = {}
for values in new_data:
    date, time, val = values.split()
    if date in local_dict:
        new_value = local_dict[date]
        local_dict[date] = new_value.replace(new_value[-1],val)
    else:
        local_dict.setdefault(date,values+ (' %s' % '0'))
print(local_dict.values())
>>>
["2018-01-17 00:00:00+01:00 49  2",
"2018-01-16 00:00:00+01:00 139 6",
"2018-01-15 00:00:00+01:00 144 0",
"2018-01-14 00:00:00+01:00 142 2",
"2018-01-13 00:00:00+01:00 141 4",
"2018-01-12 00:00:00+01:00 144 0",
"2018-01-11 00:00:00+01:00 145 0",
"2018-01-10 00:00:00+01:00 95  0"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
query_1 = [{'day': '2018-01-17 00:00:00+01:00','count_1': '49'},
           {'day': '2018-01-16 00:00:00+01:00','count_1': '139'},
           {'day': '2018-01-15 00:00:00+01:00','count_1': '144'},
           {'day': '2018-01-14 00:00:00+01:00','count_1': '142'}]


query_2 = [{'day': '2018-01-17 00:00:00+01:00','count_2': '2'},
           {'day': '2018-01-16 00:00:00+01:00','count_2': '6'},
           {'day': '2018-01-15 00:00:00+03:00','count_2': '2'},
           {'day': '2018-01-14 00:00:00+01:00','count_2': '4'}]

for a, b in zip(query_1, query_2):
    if a['day'] == b['day']:
        print a['day'] + " " + a['count_1'] + " " + b['count_2']
    else:
        print a['day'] + " " + a['count_1'] + " 0"
```

**output:**

```
2018-01-17 00:00:00+01:00 49 2
2018-01-16 00:00:00+01:00 139 6
2018-01-15 00:00:00+01:00 144 0
2018-01-14 00:00:00+01:00 142 4
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach is working like my attempt. It prints only 4 rows. If you try the whole part of my query_1 output (contain 8 rows) the code prints only 4 rows instead of 8.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use pandas, which I think the easiest method. The steps of my method was:

**1, Convert objects to DataFrame**

- `pd_query_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(query_1)`
- `pd_query_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(query_2)`

**2, Left join the two query**

- `result = (pd.merge(pd_query_1, pd_query_2, how='left', on=['day', 'day'])).fillna(0)`