# Left joint existing Django QuerySet

Tags: django, left-join, django-queryset

I am trying to left join two query in Django. Is there any way to do that? I tried to combine the result in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744137/merge-lists-while-showing-zeros-in-python/48746488#48746488) but I realized that I have to edit the result  more times in my templates so that would be more comfortable me to use left join my queries. Also In my future work would be very useful If I know the method of this. Thank you in advance for your help.

**My first query (1) and result is:**

**Query (1)**

```
 query:1=Table.objects.all()
    .filter(time_stamp__range=(before_now_week, now)).
    .filter(field__gt=0.01)
    .filter(field__lte=0.03)
    .annotate(day=TruncDay('time_stamp'))
    .values('day')
    .annotate(time=Count('time_stamp'))
    .annotate(field_count_1=Count('field'))
    .values('day','field_count_1')
    .order_by('-day')
```

**Result (1):**

```
          day              field_count_1
-------------------------|-----------
2018-01-17 00:00:00+01:00|    49
2018-01-16 00:00:00+01:00|    139
2018-01-15 00:00:00+01:00|    144
2018-01-14 00:00:00+01:00|    142
2018-01-13 00:00:00+01:00|    141
2018-01-12 00:00:00+01:00|    144
2018-01-11 00:00:00+01:00|    145
2018-01-10 00:00:00+01:00|    95
```

**My first query (2) and result is:**

**Query (2)**

```
query=Table.objects.all()
.filter(time_stamp__range=(before_now_week, now)).
.filter(field__gte=0.03)
.annotate(day=TruncDay('time_stamp'))
.values('day')
.annotate(time=Count('time_stamp'))
.annotate(field_count_2=Count('field'))
.values('day','field_count_2')
.order_by('-day')
```

**Result(2)**

```
              day            field_count_2
   -------------------------|-----------
   2018-01-17 00:00:00+01:00|     2
   2018-01-16 00:00:00+01:00|     6
   2018-01-14 00:00:00+01:00|     2
   2018-01-13 00:00:00+01:00|     4
```

**Desired result:**

```
       day                field_count_1  field_count_2
-------------------------|---------------|--------
2018-01-17 00:00:00+01:00|       49      |     2
2018-01-16 00:00:00+01:00|       139     |     6
2018-01-15 00:00:00+01:00|       144     |     0
2018-01-14 00:00:00+01:00|       142     |     2
2018-01-13 00:00:00+01:00|       141     |     4
2018-01-12 00:00:00+01:00|       144     |     0
2018-01-11 00:00:00+01:00|       145     |     0
2018-01-10 00:00:00+01:00|       95      |     0
```

Comment: The count you need to do is from the other model ?, what's the name of it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

I tried to use pandas. The steps of my method was:

**1, Convert objects to DataFrame**

- `pd_query_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(query_1)`
- `pd_query_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(query_2)`

**2, Left join the two query**

- `result = (pd.merge(pd_query_1, pd_query_2, how='left', on=['day', 'day'])).fillna(0)`